# If $v$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $c$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, must $vc$ be an eigenvalue of $AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $v$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $c$ be an eigenvalue of $B$. Is the product of $v$ and $c$ equal to an eigenvalue of $AB$?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** There are matrices $A$ and $B$, each of which have non-zero eigenvalues, such that $AB=0$.

If you need a suggestion of such matrices, you can mouse over the gray area below.

> **Suggestion:** Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: And even some with nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: I was really just trying to give the hint that we know that all the eigenvalues of the zero matrix are 0, from which it would hopefully be deduced that we then needed to pick $A$ and $B$ with non-zero eigenvalues, but in retrospect I think that is a bit too far removed for a hint.

Comment: Look how complicated my example is compared to yours...! Yours is the one, +1.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
$$
but while $1$ and $-1$ are clearly eigenvalues of both the matrices on the left, the matrix on the right does not have *any* eigenvalues (over the real numbers).

Comment: Ah, nice, that's best possible counterexample, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following matrices
$$
A=\left( \matrix{1&-1\\0&0}\right)\qquad B=\left( \matrix{0&1\\0&1}\right)
$$
and seek a counterexample.

Note: I have no idea why I did not directly set all the off-diagonal coefficients to $0$. Do it yourself while I leave it like this for self-punishment, of for a (useless) non-diagonal example.

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is an eigenvalue of $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 2\\
        \end{pmatrix},$
$3$ is an eigenvalue of $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0\\
        0 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}$ 
but $3$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 2\\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0\\
        0 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0\\
        0 & 6\\
        \end{pmatrix}.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple theoretical reasoning that the answer is no:

Pick $A,B$ to be matrices, each of them having exactly $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then the products of eigenvalues of $A,B$ can take $n^2$ distinct values, and it is easy to construct examples where the products are pairwise distinct. But $AB$ can only have $n$ eigenvalues....